# Eclipse compat RCP: Emulate "Open with" behaviour via E4 model

Tags: model, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4, eclipse-gef

I develop a workspace-based compat layer RCP which includes a Project Explorer. I contribute some editors via `plugin.xml`, so I can call `Open with ...` via the Project Explorer for some data files.

I also contribute other editors via `fragment.e4xmi` and would like to bind those to the "Open with ..." menu so that they "function the same way" for the user, i.e., can be opened the same way. I understand that this is not what is intended, but perhaps it can be "hacked"?

Generally I'm wondering whether there is a best (or at least working) practice of setting models on editors. E.g., how do I best set the model (i.e., what used to be editor input) on an editor extending GEF's `AbstractFXEditor`? And how do I share the model consistently between parts?

Comment: Open With only shows editors known by the `IEditorRegistry` and this only contains editors declared via the editors extension point - so, no, it can't be hacked.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, I see. How do you set models on editors?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'set models on editors'

Comment: Sorry, I mean pass the data you're editing in the editor into the (editor) part.

Comment: If you are asking about `AbstractFXEditor` I have no idea what input it requires - this is a completely separate question from the first part of your question.